# Can ResNet be translated to a DAG?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, conv-neural-network

I'm lookng for ways to visualize progress in a convolutional neural network (CNN), in my particular case [ResNet 16](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-resnets-c0a830a288a4)

I've been reading [an article about CNNVis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07043.pdf) which gives one approach but will only work for CNNs that translate to a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG).

Can ResNet 16 translate to a DAG?  Is there an accepted algorithm for doing this or do I have to hand-code it?